# Configuration Error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i developing a application. when i run the application in my system it is giving this error please could you help me.

> Description: An error occurred during
>   the processing of a configuration file
>   required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error
>   details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load
>   file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Extensions,
>   Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

```
Line 33:        <compilation debug="true">
Line 34:            <assemblies>
Line 35:                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
Line 36:                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
Line 37:                <add assembly ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused due to the fact that ASP.NET runtime is not able to locate an assembly which has been said to be referred in the application configuration - web.config. All you need to do to resolve this error is either remove the reference of the said assembly form your application [if you're not using any components that are available within the assembly] -or- make the assembly/DLL available in your application which is more recommended. Here's how you do that.

**On the development workstation** - Please install **[ASP.NET AJAX 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en)**.

**On the production server** - When you deploy your application if your server does not have ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 extensions installed, you will need to put the Systen.Web.Exntesions.dll in your dll which you can easily get it from

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   ASP.NET\ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX
>   Extensions\v1.0.61025

assuming your program files folder is in C: You can find more resources from the links below.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en

http://www.asp.net/ajax?mid=474

Comment: ya it is solved i just install ajax and now it is working fine thank you

Answer (score 1):

Install ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 from the following link:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en

That should also register the System.Web.Extensions assembly in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

Install .Net framework 3.5 on that  machine